# can anyone tell me why the add function doesnt work?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

my add function doesnt work but i dont know why.
i think there is a problem with my pointers.

> sgdgsgsg

1. gsgsdgsdg

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   typedef struct Node {
       char ch;
       struct Node *next;
   } Node;

   void print(const Node *list) {
       static int n;
       if (list != NULL) {
           print(list->next);
           printf("%c%d ", list->ch, n++);
       }
   }

   /* heres is the fault function */
   void add(Node **list, char c) {
       Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
       n->ch = c;
       n->next = NULL;

       if (list == NULL) {
           list = n;
       }
       else {
           Node * p = list;
           while (p->next != NULL)
               p = p->next;

           p->next = n;
       }
   }

   int main() {
       Node *head = NULL;

       add(&head, 'A');
       add(head, 'B');
       add(head, 'C');
       print(head);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
Node **list
```

`list` is of `Node**` type and `n` is of `Node*` type. Hence this

```
list = n;
```

is not correct. It should be

```
(*list) = n;
```

And when `list` is `NULL`, this check

```
if (list == NULL) {
    list = n;
}
```

is not correct, it should be

```
if ((*list) == NULL) {
    (*list) = n;
}
```

Also call to `add()` here

```
add(head, 'B');
add(head, 'C');
```

is wrong, it should be

```
add(&head, 'A');
add(&head, 'B'); /* pass the address of head */
add(&head, 'C');/* pass the address of head */
```

Lastly enable all compiler warning and read those warnings and analyze. For e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpedantic -Werror test.c
```